# Struct that has a value of a struct with a generic type

Tags: generics, struct, rust, i2c

Suppose I have a `struct` that uses a generic type (BNO055 is a sensor):

```rust
pub struct BNO055<T: I2CDevice + Sized> {
    pub i2cdev: T,
    pub mode: BNO055OperationMode,
}
```

I also have another `struct` that has the BNO055 as a field:

```rust
pub struct IMU {
    device: bno055::BNO055
}
```

Attempting to compile this code results in an error, with the compiler saying:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
   --> src/modules/sensors/imu.rs:553:13
    |
553 |     device: bno055::BNO055
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

If I add a generic type to the `struct`, like so:

```rust
pub struct IMU<D: I2CDevice + Sized>{
    device: bno055::BNO055<D>
}
```

And then `impl` a function:

```rust
impl<D: I2CDevice + Sized> IMU<D> {
    pub fn init(imu_addr: u16) -> Self {
        let mut i2c_dev = LinuxI2CDevice::new("/dev/i2c-1", imu_addr).unwrap();
        let mut imu_dev = bno055::BNO055::new(i2c_dev).unwrap();

        IMU {
            device: imu_dev
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/modules/sensors/imu.rs:567:21
    |
567 |             device: imu_dev
    |                     ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `modules::sensors::imu::bno055::i2cdev::linux::LinuxI2CDevice`
    |
```

`imu_dev` is of the type `BNO055`, so I assume that it should properly fit the generic's constraints. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: would be easy to help you with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `init()` function is supposed to create an `IMU<D>` instance for any `D`  specified by the caller (provided `D` satisfies the `I2CDevice + Sized` bounds):

```
impl<D: I2CDevice + Sized> IMU<D> {
    pub fn init(imu_addr: u16) -> Self {
```

...but it always tries to return an `IMU<LinuxI2CDevice>`.

(edit) In my testing, the `error[E0308]: mismatched types` is explained in a note that follows it, which should look like this:

```
note: expected type `......::BNO055<D>`
         found type `......::BNO055<LinuxI2CDevice>`
```

(/edit)

To fix this, you could make `init()` non-generic, e.g. by changing the impl to `impl IMU<LinuxI2CDevice>`.

P.S. You call `BNO055` a "type" and are trying to use it as a type... I'm not sure about terminology, but note that after you define a struct as being generic over some type parameter `D`, the struct name alone doesn't represent a concrete type, but rather a family of related - but incompatible - types. You have to provide some type in place of `D`: either another type parameter `BNO055<T>` or a specific type `BNO055<LinuxI2CDevice>` - to get a type.

Keep in mind the alternatives to using generics: making the `I2CDevice` a enum or keeping it a trait, but using it as a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html), e.g. `pub i2cdev: Box<dyn I2CDevice>`.

Comment: Thank you! In the future, how would I know that `init()` returns a `IMU<LinuxI2CDevice>`? This return type wasn't indicated anywhere.

Comment: @AkashBhave I've added an (edit) to my answer with the compiler output you should have gotten as part of the error, it hints at that. In general, to see the inferred type for a value like `IMU { device: imu_dev }` you could assign it to a temporary variable and check its type in your IDE, or make the compiler report the expression's type by assigning it to a variable of an incompatible type like `()`: `let foo: () = IMU { device: imu_dev };`.

Comment: Thanks, your response has been very helpful. I should have probably been more general with my question, but I'm still very new to Rust and didn't know how to generalize it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!